# Garbage collection when using multiple local variables with the same name

Tags: lua

Consider the following code:

```
local v = "hello"
a = function() print(v) end
local v = "world"
b = function() print(v) end
a()
b()
```

The output is:

```
hello
world
```

Normally, I'd expect that `hello` would be marked for garbage collection as soon as it is overwritten by `world`. However, since `a` references `hello` I assume that `hello` won't be garbage collected as long as `a` still there. Thus, doing

```
a = nil
```

would mark both `a` and `hello` for garbage collection. Is that right?

Comment: Are you asking about how much memory is being used, or do you only care about which values are somehow accessible at given points in the program?

Comment: Just about the memory consumption. The strings in my example are just placeholders to illustrate the issue. In reality, those are large tables needing lots of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, I'd expect that `hello` would be marked for garbage collection
> as soon as it is overwritten by `world`.

hello is not overwritten by world. It is just no longer referenced by `v`

`a = nil` will mark the function value for garbage collection as it removes the only reference to it.

With that function value gone nothing refers to "hello" anymore, so it will also be collected.

Answer (score 1):

Two local variables of the same name are technically two different variables. Variable scope lasts until the end of a code block. The big question is whether the garbage collector can detect shadowed variables. If it can't, the first `v` will remain stuck in memory until the end of the block.

In the following code, I use tables instead of strings. Since string literals are embedded in the byte code, using strings can make it more difficult to see memory usage.

```
local function showMemory()
  -- Do a full GC cycle to get a clean memory reading.
  collectgarbage()
  -- Show memory usage in bytes.
  print(collectgarbage'count' * 1024)
end

showMemory()
local v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
showMemory()
local v = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
showMemory()
```

Output:

```
24003.0
24291.0
24507.0
```

The first `v` adds 288 bytes to memory usage. The second `v` adds 216 bytes.

Now let's see what happens when we use `do`--`end` to force the first `v` out of scope:

```
local function showMemory()
  collectgarbage()
  print(collectgarbage'count' * 1024)
end

showMemory()
do
  local v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  showMemory()
end
showMemory()
local v = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
showMemory()
```

Output:

```
24019.0
24307.0
24091.0
24307.0
```

Here, we see that memory usage is exactly the same after each `v` declaration. It clearly makes a big difference whether both `v`s are in the same scope.

From this, I conclude that declaring a local variable **does not** cause previous variables of the same name to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. In my original code the first `v` is probably not even garbage collected when setting `a=nil` because it is still in scope even though it is no longer accessible in that scope because all further references to `v` will reference the second `v`. So if the garbage collector was clever, it *should* be able to detect that the first `v` can be collected because it's no longer accessible. However, from your observations, it doesn't seem to be capable of doing that...